# Include blade template without interpreting html

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a blade template that has some HTML and some JS code. For both case 1 and 2 I'd like to use the same template as it's used in multiple places.

Case 1: include the template with the normal behaviour, so that the code in the template gets executed. This works with the normal behaviour of using `@include('template')`

Case 2: include the template without the HTML and JS actually being interpreted.

Now I could solve this by making it an x-template component, and then pass a variable to that component that will conditionally wrap the template in `<xmp></xmp>`.

But the problem is that I use Highlightjs, and that doesn't work if the code is in those `xmp` tags. It needs to be in `<pre><code></code></pre>`.

So I'm wondering if you can pass some parameter or do something to include a blade template without actually interpreting the code that's being included.

**Update**

A bit more clarification. Let's say `template.blade.php` has this:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
    alert('test');
</script>
```

In case 1 using `@include('template')` should alert test when the page is loaded.

In case 2 using `@include('template')` (but then another way I guess, that's what this question is about) I'd like it to display the code without interpreting it, like would happen when using `<code>{{ '<div id="test"></div><script>alert('test');</script>' }}</code>`.

Comment: What do you mean without the HTML and JS being interpreted? The HTML will only get "interpreted" when it reaches the browser.

Comment: use @component in blade

Comment: I have updated the question for clarity

Comment: This question is still too broad. As I said before, the browser will interpret the HTML and JS you send it so broadly speaking you can't do what you are looking to do. If you want to render the HTML code rather than send correct HTML then you can use `{{ "<html>bla bla</html>" }}` to do that which will use `htmlspacialchars` to replace HTML special characters with code that the browser will display.  Now I guess one could ask how to use the text rendered by `@include` as a variable and manipulate it which could itself be a different question if you want to ask that.

Comment: OK, thanks for the background info.